# Spring boot JPA - JSON without nested object with OneToMany relation

Tags: java, json, hibernate, orm, spring-boot

I have a project which deals with some ORM mapping of objects (there are some `@OneToMany` relations etc).

I am using REST interface to treat these objects and Spring JPA to manage them in the API.

This is an example of one of my POJOs:

```
@Entity
public class Flight {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String dateOfDeparture;
  private double distance;
  private double price;
  private int seats;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Destination fromDestination;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Destination toDestination;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "flight")
  private List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

When making a request, I have to specify everything in the JSON:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "reservations": [
    {}
  ],
  "name": "string",
  "dateOfDeparture": "string",
  "distance": 0,
  "price": 0,
  "seats": 0,
  "from": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  },
  "to": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  }
}
```

What I would prefer, is actually specifying the id of referenced object instead of their whole bodies, like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "reservations": [
    {}
  ],
  "name": "string",
  "dateOfDeparture": "string",
  "distance": 0,
  "price": 0,
  "seats": 0,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 2
}
```

Is that even possible? Could someone give me some insight on how to do this? I am only finding tutorials on how to do the opposite (the solution I already have).

Comment: You can try find this useful - http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For this purpose you should use pair of Jackson annotations to your entity model:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
protected Location from;
```

Your serialized JSON will look instead of this:

```
{
    "from": {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "New-York"
    } 
}
```

like this:

```
{
    "from": 3
}
```

As mentioned in [official documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityReference.html):

> @JsonIdentityReference - optional annotation that can be used for
>   customizing details of a reference to Objects for which "Object
>   Identity" is enabled (see [JsonIdentityInfo](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html))
>
> `alwaysAsId = true` used as marker to indicate whether all referenced
>   values are to be serialized as ids (true);
>
> **Note** that if value of 'true' is used, deserialization may require additional contextual information, and possibly using a custom id
>   resolver - the default handling may not be sufficient.

Comment: is @JsonIdentityInfo necessary here?

Answer (score 2):

You can only ignore your JSON content using **@JsonIgnore** annotation.
The field which you want to hide in your JSON at there you can annotate that with **@JsonIgnore**.
You can change your JSON like this :

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "reservations": [
        {}
    ],
    "name": "string",
    "dateOfDeparture": "string",
    "distance": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "seats": 0,
    "from": {
        "id": 0
    },
    "to": {
        "id": 0
    }
}
```

But You can't like this:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "reservations": [
        {}
    ],
    "name": "string",
    "dateOfDeparture": "string",
    "distance": 0,
    "price": 0,
    "seats": 0,
    "from": 0,
    "to": 1
}
```

Comment: I think the second part isn't true as show by the other answer.

Comment: I agree with @Amit khanduri

Comment: This does not work if one request needs the nested data and other doesnt. Let's say I have a shop and an item. I want an item name of which I have and I want to retreive it with couple of shop details. Do you know a way to do that in spring boot?